# wrong url in request by refreshing page in SPA/page.js working on dev lite-server

Tags: request, localhost, url-parameters, lite-server

I have SPA with page.js for routing running localy on a dev server.
the DB sever is runned on http://localhost:3030 port
dev server: http://localhost:3000
If initiate page with params in its url for first time there is no problem: borwser loads correctly the data from DB server with correct urls:
http://localhost:3030/data/albums/6bb7659d-e094-4e6d-bc08-0901e6a8784e
page url is: http://localhost:3000/albums/6bb7659d-e094-4e6d-bc08-0901e6a8784e
but when I'm trying to refresh the page
browser try to load data from this wrong url:
http://localhost:3000/albums/6bb7659d-e094-4e6d-bc08-0901e6a8784e

and the app.js can not load too:
http://localhost:3000/albums/src/app.js

Obviously the dev server Lite-server change the localhost addres port of DB requests from 3030 to 3000, which is his own addres, not the correct localhost of DB server.
How can to proceed, config the server, so work properly with url requests without changing it?

I try to find some setting for bs-confing.json file, but it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
Path in the attribute src of script element in index.js
should be absolute `src="/src/app.js"`
NOT relative `src="./src/app.js"`